# Uniformly continuous maps between topological groups

Tags: group-theory, analysis, continuity, topological-groups, uniform-continuity

Let $G$ be a topological group. For every neighbourhood $U$ of the identity, let $L_U$ be the set of all pairs $(x,y) \in G \times G$ such that $x^{-1} y \in U$.

For topological groups $G$ and $H$, a map $f \colon G \to H$ is called *left uniformly continuous* if for every open neighbourhood $V$ of the identity in $H$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of the identity in $G$ such that $(f(x),f(y)) \in L_V$ for all $(x,y) \in L_U$.

Is the map $G \times G \to G$, $(x,y) \mapsto x^{-1}y$ left uniformly continuous?
That is for any open neighbourhood $W$ of the identity does there exists neighbourhoods $U,V$ of the identity such that $(x_1^{-1}x_2, y_1^{-1}y_2) \in L_W$ whenever $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) \in L_{U \times V}$.

If not, is there a nice example to show this is not true?

Comment: An observation: This is true for all abelian topological groups.

Comment: Are there further errors with my answer that lead you to reject it?

Comment: Your answer may or may not be correct but I can't follow it.

Comment: I think its reasonably clear, but regardless, it is the result that is important. I'd play around with the isometries of the plane to see why the left regularity is failing. More generally, I suspect that if G/(Z(G)) is non compact then the left regularity fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is not generally left uniformly continuous. I'll begin with some remarks, then demonstrate the existence of a group where the map is not left uniformly continuous.

Note that $((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) \in L_{V \times W}$ if and only if $x_1^{-1} x_2 \in V$ and $y_1^{-1} y_2\in W.$ We need to use these conditions to force $(x_1^{-1}y_1, x_2^{-1}y_2) \in L_U,$ which is equivalent to $\phi((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = y_1^{-1}x_1 x_2^{-1} y_2 \in U.$ Now, a general element of $L_V$ is of the form $(x, xv)$ where $v\in V$ and $x$ is any element of $G$, and similarly $(y, yw)$ is a general element of $L_W$. Furthermore $\phi((x, y), (xv, yw)) = y^{-1} x v^{-1} x^{-1} y w$ so $$\phi(L_{V\times W}) = \bigcup_{x\in G} x V^{-1} x^{-1} W \text{ and } \bigcup_{x\in G} x V^{-1} x^{-1} \subseteq \phi(L_{V\times W}),$$ and therefore we need to find some open neighborhood of the identity, $V$, such that all its conjugates are contained in an arbitrary open set. In general, this is not possible, which we demonstrate by looking at a particular (non compact) group.

Let $G$ be the group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric, so $G$ is the group generated by rigid rotations and translations of the plane (and lets not have reflections, though this makes no real difference, its a separate connected component of the group). I claim that for all open neighborhoods of the identity $V$, and all positive real numbers, $l$,  there is some translation $t\in G$ and $v\in V$ such that $d(t v t^{-1} (\vec{0}), \vec{0}) = l$. To see this, note that $V$ contains some rotation, $v$, that fixes $\vec{0}$ and rotates the plane by $\epsilon >0.$ Then $t(a, b) = \left( a + \frac{l}{2\sin(\epsilon/2)}, b \right)$ is as required. In fact, for every point in the plane, there is an element of $\{ tvt^{-1}: t \text{ is a translation}\}$ that maps the origin to that point.

Therefore, if we let $U$ be the set of isometries that move the origin by strictly less than $1$, no matter what neighborhoods, $V$ and $W$, of the identity we choose, $\phi(L_{V\times W}) \not\subseteq U.$

I think that's all correct, now. [This pdf](http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/PadicGroups/topgroups.pdf) was quite helpful to get me on the right track, especially lemma 4.2.

Comment: I feel like I've editted this so many times that its lost all meaning. From here on out, all the errors that are left are deliberate... sorry.

Comment: There are quite a few mistakes and issues with this which makes me uneasy with this answer. First of all your actions are the wrong way round.

(1) $((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) \in L_{V \times W}$ if and only if $(x_1^{-1}x_2) \in V$ and $(y_1^{-1}y_2) \in W$.

(2) $\varphi$ is not a map on $G \times G \times G \times G$. We want to show that $(y_1^{-1}x_1x_2^{-1}y_2) \in W$ for a particular choice $U$ such that $(x_1^{-1}x_2) \in U$ and $(y_1^{-1}y_2) \in U$.

Comment: I'll fix the actions. I understand that $\phi$ is not an action on $G^4$ but on $(G^2)^2$ but that is not a substantive difference imo. If $x_1^{-1}x_2 \in U$ then there is an $x\in G$ and $u\in U$ such that $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = x u_x$, similarly for $y_1 = y$, $y_2 = yu_y$, and so $\phi((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = y^{-1} x u_x^{-1} x^{-1} y u_y$ and again we have to find a neighborhood of the identity such that the conjugates of the neighborhood are contained in an arbitrary neighborhood. This can't be done in the isometries of the plane.

Comment: I think after looking at this, the idea is correct and in general this map is not uniformly continuous